# MDCOutlinedTextField not displaying properly

Tags: swift, material-design

[image]

I'm using Material Design for iOS.

I called the `textField.text = "textvalue"` in `viewDidAppear()` but it doesn't display properly. But if I wrap the said line of code to an `UITimer` with 1 second interval it display as expected. I think the issue is something with the MDCOutlinedTextField animation but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Is there something I missed when setting up a `MDCOutlinedTextField`? Any idea?